# Bluetooth enabling window is opened

Tags: java, android

I just started learning Java and dealing with Bluetooth. To enable Bluetooth, I use the following code:

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
```

If Bluetooth is turned off, when executing this code the user will have a window with a choice between "Enable Bluetooth" or "Cancel". 
I need to execute another code when the user makes his choice and this window closes.

**How can I check if this window is open now or not?**

I know there is a "onActivityResult" method that returns the result when the window closes, but for definite I can't use it, so I'm looking for other ways.

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MyBluetooth {

  private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
  private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;



  public void Init() {
    bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
      Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
      startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Care to elaborate why you couldn't use `onActivityResult()`?
Because that is where you would handle your application when that window closes and run your desired codes.